# Laravel register extra fields placement

Tags: laravel

I have some extra fields that need to be filled right after a user is registered.

Right now I've done it with an Event and couple of Listeners but I can't seem to find an elegant way to carry the data from the Registration page to the Listener so it can insert it in.

Should I use Events/Listeners or is there a better way (without changing the registerController).

I was thinking of getting rid of the Events and redirecting to another form right after registering where the other data to be inserted, but it's just couple of fields, so if there's a better way I would appreciate you sharing it.

Latest Laravel version with the default Auth installed.

Comment: where do these extra fields come from ?

Comment: Well for the sake of the example let's say there's a Profile model/table with age and gender in there and I need those populated with the registering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you said without changing the RegisterController, but this way it doesn't change any of the logic inside it:

```
class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    use RegistersUsers;

    protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
    {
        // ... your code here

        return redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
}
```

If your class has a **registered()** method it will be called right after a successful registration, so you can save the additional data there and then redirect the user.

Comment: So basically Events are not needed in this case.

Comment: @MaximilianBerbechelov, its ok to hook to the event, but in this case Laravel gives a better way to handle additional logic right after the registration.